# How to avoid input checkbox work in whole division except the targeted

Tags: html, css, input

I have a button **Change Language**, when clicked, it opens lists `<ul class="dd-menu">`. But even I click out side (Pink area) the Change Language, it works which I want to avoid.

I want it to work (open the lists) only when clicking the red **Change Language** button `<div class="dd-button">`.

```css
label.language.dropdown {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.dd-button {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 8px 18px 8px 18px;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: fit-content;
}

.dd-button:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

.dd-input {
    display: none;
}

.dd-menu {
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: var(--box-clr);
    list-style-type: none;
    width: fit-content;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: justify;
}

.dd-input+.dd-menu {
    display: none;
}

.dd-input:checked+.dd-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dd-menu li {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}

.dd-menu li:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}

.dd-menu li a {
    display: block;
    margin: -10px -20px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
span.closebutton {
    color: var(--black-clr);
    position: absolute;
    top: -5%;
    background: var(--main-clr);
    padding: 6px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    right: -3%;
    line-height: 12px;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer
}
@media(min-width:750px){
    .dd-menu {
        width: 45%;
        left: 27.1% ;
    }
}
@media(min-width: 1650px) {
    .dd-menu {
        max-width: 23%;
        left: 38.1% !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<label class="language dropdown" style="background-color: pink">
    <div class="dd-button"> Change Language
    </div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="dd-input" id="test">
    <ul class="dd-menu">
      <li>
         Hindi
      </li>
       <li>
         English
      </li>
       <li>
         Spanish
      </li>
    </ul>
   <span class="closebutton">x</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div.language.dropdown {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.dd-button {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px 18px 8px 18px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: fit-content;
}

.dd-button:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

span.closebutton {
  color: var(--black-clr);
  position: absolute;
  top: -5%;
  background: var(--main-clr);
  padding: 6px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  right: -3%;
  line-height: 12px;
  vertical-align: inherit;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer
}

.dd-input {
  display: none;
}

.dd-menu {
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: var(--box-clr);
  list-style-type: none;
  width: fit-content;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: justify;
}

.dd-input+.dd-menu {
  display: none;
}

.dd-input:checked+.dd-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dd-menu li {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}

.dd-menu li:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.dd-menu li a {
  display: block;
  margin: -10px -20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

@media(min-width:750px) {
  .dd-menu {
    width: 45%;
    left: 27.1%;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 1650px) {
  .dd-menu {
    max-width: 23%;
    left: 38.1% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="language dropdown" style="background-color: pink">
  <label for="test" class="dd-button"> Change Language
    </label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="dd-input" id="test">
  <ul class="dd-menu">
    <li>
      Hindi
    </li>
    <li>
      English
    </li>
    <li>
      Spanish
    </li>
    <span class="closebutton">x</span>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The thing you need to know is how label works, **The for attribute in label must match the value of the id attribute of checkbox.** When absent, the label is associated with the element’s content [That's what happened on your html] . Also, note that the id should be unique on the page.if you didn't understand anything plz ask

Comment: Can you also make in such a way that close button works ?

Comment: You want close button to appear once we click change language?

Comment: Yes. You got me

Comment: Just add another label same as above just change the text it will work,

Comment: Element ul not allowed as child of element label in this context

Comment: The element label must not appear as a descendant of the label element.